# What does it mean the notation $L^2(0,T;U)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation, lp-spaces

I am studying second order parabolic equations, but i can't find in my book what the notation $L^2(0,T;U)$ means. Can anybody explain this to me? Thanks

Comment: $L^2$ usually means functions whose square is integrable.

Comment: This may be relevant. I've seen $L^p(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ to denote functions $f$ that are $|f|^p$ integrable with respect to $\mu$ measure, where $\mathcal{A}$ is the associated sigma algebra on the space $\Omega$.

Comment: Perhaps naming the book you are using would have avoided a lot non-sense in this discussion. To add something constructive, you might also be interested in the [Bochner integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U$ is some other normed vector space. In this case $L^2([0,T];U)$, sometimes lazily written as $L^2(0,T;U)$, consists of functions $f$ from $[0,T]$ to $U$ such that $\int_0^T \| f(t) \|^2 dt<\infty$, where $\| \cdot \|$ is the norm on $U$.

This notation is used in, for instance, *Partial Differential Equations* by Evans. Most commonly the $U$ in question is an $L^p$ space or a Sobolev space. I think this may be the usage that you are seeing.

Comment: Yes, this is the usage I was looking for :)